# Does any mirror of https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09 exist?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mirror

I'm looking for a mirror to the plugin install site for Eclipse 2021-09. URLs with "download" and "update" at the front seem to be blocked by my provider.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.: The following should work:

https://rhlx01.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/2021-09/

You didn't write where in the world you are located.
Here is a nice mirror list (maybe it is also blocked for you, but maybe you can read it from somewhere else). just append the subdirectory after /eclipse/

https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/archive/mirror.php

Comment: Thanks for this. Strangely I get even with this mirror in Eclipse the error "Unable to read repository at https://rhlx01.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/2021-09/content.xml." - Even stranger, the URL from the error message (https://rhlx01.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/2021-09/content.xml.) doesn't seem to be a valid URL at all. (It gives a 404 on every machine.)

Comment: Hmm. I can see the location's contents if I paste `https://rhlx01.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/2021-09/` into the "Work with" field in the "Install new software" dialog and hit enter. How have you tried to use it?